# close iPhone simulator from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically close iOS Simulator when application is stopped in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490238/automatically-close-ios-simulator-when-application-is-stopped-in-xcode)

like the title says, is it possible to have code within Xcode app stop and close the simulator when done? The reason that I am asking is if I forget to manually close the simulator and leave Xcode running with the simulator running, the Macbook gets warm due to CPU cycle requirement to run the simulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490238/automatically-close-ios-simulator-when-application-is-stopped-in-xcode

Comment: Check out http://macosxautomation.com/ for excellent information on Mac OS X Automator with lots of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Use applescript to close the Simulator:

```
tell application "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app"
quit
end tell
```

And launch it from your app like this:

```
NSString * pstrScript= @"tell application \"/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app\"\nquit\nend tell";
if(!pstrScript)
{
    NSLog(@"Error ReadAlbumArtitunesOperation::runWIthParameters:: if(!pstrScript)\n");
    return nil;
}

_script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:pstrScript];
if(!_script)
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR ReadAlbumArtItunesOperation:: runWithParameters::  if(!_script)\n");
    return nil;
}

NSAppleEventDescriptor* desc= [_script executeAndReturnError:&_errorInfo];


if( _errorInfo ) 
{
     NSLog(@"Couldn't run script: err=%@",[_errorInfo description]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using AppleScript.  The Automator and associated technologies are excellent

Comment: Also +1 for AppleScript, however you should edit this to show the up to date simulator location in /Xcode.app.

Comment: Thanks yall. I used the location of iOS Simulator on my machine. So to anyone who uses this and it doesn't work, locate iOS Simulator and put that path in place of /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app